# Android: Is there a way to avoid adding multiple SHA keys into Firebase when working in a team?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, sha, one-time-password

I'm working in a team that uses OTP to verify users. We've noticed that if we wanted to all locally be able to use OTP, then we'd have to input multiple SHA keys into Firebase for each person in the team.

My question is, is there anyway to get around having to do this? Maybe if there was someway to make it so that all the team members could get away with only using the same exact SHA 1 and SHA 256 keys?

Bonus question, if we were to input the production SHA keys into Firebase then the production version of the App should be able to OTP without any problems right?

Thank You All.